# Getting information from website onto mobile app

Tags: android, ios, web-services, mobile, html-parsing

I don't have a specific programming question but rather a general question and hints on where to begin. I am trying to grab content from one of our news sites and parse into a mobile app. I was thinking I would use one of the many html parsing libraries available to achieve this. Is this the recommended method in achieving this? Id like to make a mobile app for both leading OS (Android, iOS), would parsing the html content via web service be the smarter thing to do here? any general ideas, articles, tips or hints would be helpful.

- No API unfortunately.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the website you are wanting to retrieve data from has an API, I would first check there to see if it will provide you with the appropriate information. Retrofit is a great library for working with APIs:

http://square.github.io/retrofit/

Here is a tutorial page:

http://www.androidhive.info/2016/05/android-working-with-retrofit-http-library/

It is possible the website that you are wanting to retrieve data from does not have an API. If this is the case, you can use a library such as JSoup to parse the webpage.

https://jsoup.org/

They provide plenty of examples in the documentation.

Some news sites won't provide you with the full article through the API, but what you can do is get the URL link through the API and then use JSoup to parse through the appropriate `<p>` or `<div>` tags on that page.

Hope you find this information helpful. Let me know if you need any further explanation or have any further questions!

Comment: this is great, thank you so much for taking the time to answer. This can be used on a native app, correct? would you suggest/recommend the web service route?

Comment: Hey, sorry for the delayed response. Yes it can be used for a native app. Just import the dependencies into your project and you will be all set. Here is a link to a tutorial on consuming web services http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/88b6e5/how-to-call-web-service-in-android-using-soap/. Additionally, here is a great resource when searching for libraries for Android https://android-arsenal.com/. Hope you find these helpful!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you don't have any API, I would first develop a web service that takes care of the parsing and gives me the required data in JSON from your news site.

Next, I would call this web service from my mobile client.

If the data that you're parsing is supposed to be secure, you might want to do some authentication on server side but I am not very sure what exactly you're doing.

Comment: fantastic, thanks for answering and your input.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Volley Google library

https://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html

http://www.androidhive.info/2014/05/android-working-with-volley-library-1/